# how I can update SearchView?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, androidx

I'm using `createVoiceAppSearchIntent` function from SearchView and this method still using `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT` and is crashing my app.

Causing `Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent. Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.`

There's something that I can do about?

Here is the log:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
       at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:382)
       at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivityAsUser(PendingIntent.java:465)
       at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:451)
       at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:415)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.createVoiceAppSearchIntent(SearchView.java:1594)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.onVoiceClicked(SearchView.java:1251)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView$5.onClick(SearchView.java:991)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7792)
       at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7769)
       at android.view.View.access$3800(View.java:910)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30218)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8669)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

Comment: If something is **requeried** maybe you should **add** this ...

Comment: @Selvin but it's function inside SearchView is passing a wrong Flag.

Comment: There is no `createVoiceAppSearchIntent` in `android.widget.SearchView` nor in `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView`

Comment: @Selvin My log error says different. I edited to put the log error

Comment: so it's internals of the implementation ... while google may forget about changing the stuff for new api version but it's less likely than you forgot to upgrade appcompat's version to be compatible with 31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to update required for PendingIntent for apps targeting version 31 or above.

Try updating androidx.appcompat.widget

```
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1"
```

Not sure what is the exact version that fixed this, but latest will do the work.

Comment: It worked out. But I needed to update my build tools too.